# Unable to change email updates period on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, email, tag-filters, subscription

I have subscribed for email notifications for [Java tag on Software Engineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java), and follows link from email to change email preferences.

But then when I press edit and change period (i.e. How often?) to 15 minutes, and hit *subscribe*  button, then I still see it as "Emailing every day to".

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Can't reproduce. What browser are you using? Can you check the browser's console to see if there are errors when you click the "subscribe" button?

Comment: Using latest chrome. When I inspect it in console I see that regardless what option i have selected there is still form param freq=3 going with POST http://stackexchange.com/filters/subscribe/4798

Comment: And errors in console?

Comment: No error and just that one POST request with 200 OK. But notice that on stackoverflow I was able to do that without probles - only on programmers site i have this issue.

Comment: Weird. When I tried to output the checked radio button to console I got this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ovdSR.png meaning there are two checked buttons with same name! Will leave this for SE developer to solve, but something there is buggy indeed.